# Visual Studio still looking for old dll after renaming

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC 3 project, which i renamed from

```
FooApplication
```

to

```
FooApplication.BackOffice
```

Now when I try to run the application, i m getting an exception as follows:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FooApplication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or ...
```

Which actually should be `FooApplication.BackOffice`.

I did rename the Project from properties and also renamed the folder and added to Solution again.

How can i fix this?

**EDIT:** When i build the project in the output window, I can see `FooApplication.BackOffice` is generated.

Comment: Have you full rebuild your solution? (Just in case you FooApplication is referenced elsewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you should change the namespace to FooApplication.BackOffice, see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Apply VS refactoring. You may have changed some settings, but those apply on new files created after this change has been done.

**EDIT**

If this doesn't work, there are a few more options...

- use Find and Replace function of Visual Studio manually check
- relevant files (especially those auto-generated by visual studio) and
  replace as needed

Comment: @DarthVader, what exactly did you try? If you do it correctly, it should work. If not, try to apply Marc's advice as well.

Comment: Here is the error: in MVC view, types are still defined as FooApplication. Rather than FooApplication.BackOffice. and refactoring doesnt work for that. Can you change your answer so i can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this a couple of times.

Delete your bin folder then rebuild the solution. When you rebuild vs solutions it doesn't remove invalid files. The error is misinformation, it should complain that the old dll still exists.

After the rebuild it should be fine.